# Weird but simple to understand bug... UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating is not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

Edit: The UIActivityIndicatorView thinks it isn't on the screen... all values show that it isn't, but when you look at screen, it is there.

So... this is sort of driving me insane.

I am using https://github.com/fphilipe/PHFComposeBarView

I am editing it so that I can put a UIActivityIndicatorView in place of the button on the right when loading...

As it stands, I can perfectly start animating the UIActivityIndicatorView... but when I have to stopAnimating it, it won't stop and it won't disappear.

I have `hidesWhenStopped = true` and I know that everything is happening on the main thread.

In fact, when I use `println` or `NSLog`, I see that the UIActivityIndicatorView thinks that it is hidden... when it clearly is not.

Anyone know why it might not be working?

Edit: I even tried to mitigate this by instead having the UIActivityIndicatorView always be animated and just add it to the view or remove it from its superview... Again, when I needed to remove it, it wouldn't work...

```
- (void)startLoading {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self loadIndicator] startAnimating];

    });
}

- (void)stopLoading {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self loadIndicator] stopAnimating];
    });
}

@synthesize button = _button;
- (UIButton *)button {
    if (!_button) {
        _button = [PHFComposeBarView_Button buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake([self bounds].size.width - kHorizontalSpacing - kButtonRightMargin - kButtonTouchableOverlap,
                                  [self bounds].size.height - kButtonBottomMargin - kButtonHeight,
                                  2 * kButtonTouchableOverlap,
                                  kButtonHeight);
        [_button setFrame:frame];
        [_button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5f, 0, 0, 0)];
        [_button setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
        [_button setTitle:[self buttonTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIColor *disabledColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:240.0f/360.0f saturation:0.03f brightness:0.58f alpha:1.0f];
        [_button setTitleColor:disabledColor forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        UIColor *enabledColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:211.0f/360.0f saturation:1.0f brightness:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
        [_button setTitleColor:enabledColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UILabel *label = [_button titleLabel];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize]];
    }

    return _button;
}

@synthesize loadIndicator = _loadIndicator;
- (UIActivityIndicatorView *)loadIndicator {
    if (!_loadIndicator) {

        UIButton *rightButton = [self button];

        _loadIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([rightButton frame].origin.x + [rightButton frame].size.width / 2.0f - [rightButton frame].size.height / 2.0f, [rightButton frame].origin.y, [rightButton frame].size.height, [rightButton frame].size.height)];

        [_loadIndicator setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

        _loadIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
        _loadIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;

    }

    return _loadIndicator;
}
```

That should be the relevant code...

In my ViewController:

```
var composeBarView: PHFComposeBarView {
    var viewBounds = self.view
    var frame = CGRectMake(0, viewBounds.frame.height - PHFComposeBarViewInitialHeight, viewBounds.frame.width, PHFComposeBarViewInitialHeight)

    var composeBarView = PHFComposeBarView(frame: frame)

    composeBarView.maxLinesCount = 6
    composeBarView.placeholder = "Write some text"
    composeBarView.buttonTitle = "Reply"
    composeBarView.delegate = self

    composeBarView.buttonTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "056A85")
    composeBarView.textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return composeBarView
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you are creating the ComposeBarView and working on it?

Comment: Updated with the code I have. That is basically the code responsible within PHFComposeBarView

Comment: This will be easier to debug if you can make your project available.

Comment: I might be able to get an example project going... give me a moment

Comment: @Ishanhanda added example project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using a computed property, not a lazy property, so each time you call `self.composeBarView` you're creating a new instance. Your code uses the passed view to start animating, but to stop animating you're always creating a new view which obviously hasn't been displayed yet.

Change your code to:

```
lazy var composeBarView: PHFComposeBarView = {
    var viewBounds = self.view
    var frame = CGRectMake(0, viewBounds.frame.height - PHFComposeBarViewInitialHeight, viewBounds.frame.width, PHFComposeBarViewInitialHeight)

    var composeBarView = PHFComposeBarView(frame: frame)

    composeBarView.maxLinesCount = 6
    composeBarView.placeholder = "Write some text"
    composeBarView.buttonTitle = "Reply"
    composeBarView.delegate = self

    composeBarView.textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return composeBarView
}()
```